# Locking frame rate to 60 in the editor

Tags: unity

My game runs at several hundred frames per second. I want to limit it to 60. So I used

```
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
```

This works on the iPhone. But in the editor it only reduced the frame rate to around 80-90. Am I missing yet another setting?

Mac OSX Mavericks.

Comment: How are you measuring the frame rate?

Comment: @KellyThomas: The statistics window in the editor (the "stats" button on the top right)

Comment: The FPS in the editor stats is considered "unreliable", people looking for accurate number will often [roll their own](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond).

Comment: KellyThomas is correct - I have noticed a difference of about 20 to 30 fps with the editor stats and a simple fps measurement script.  The stats are almost always higher than what you're really getting.

Answer (score 3):

For the target frame rate to be applied in the editor it is important that the vsync is disabled.

This can be changed using the [Quality Settings GUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html) by selecting "Don't sync" or programmatically:

```
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0
```

Comment: Hm, I think it helped, but it is still at 70-80 frames.

Answer (score 3):

Note that "[targetFrameRate is ignored in the editor"](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html).

Also, it worth noting that FPS number displayed in the Editor stats window is not accurate at all. I even came to a point where I wonder if the number displayed is about Frames Per Seconds.

I suggest you to use a [custom script](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond) instead of using Editor stats.

Comment: "By 'the editor' they don't mean the game view in the editor. They mean the editor itself. You can run your own code in the editor by using ExecuteInEditMode, but this will ignore these framerate settings. In the editor's game view, these settings are applied without a problem." - [Nyubis](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/300467/how-to-limit-frame-rate-in-unity-editor.html)